# Line of code not working. Don't know why?

Tags: vba, excel

I found a way to grab new information in a spreadsheet based on criteria.  My problem is with one line that gives me an application defined or object defined error.  I do not know why this is happening.  The explanation of what this code does is in the comments.  Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub Check_Price_Click()
    'This code block runs through the data and if the first column is equal to the current date and the third column is equal to a Brand
    'then copy new data to different workbook and repeat
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    'This line of code is not working
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 157)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Sales1\Dropbox\Davids Files\Macro Work\Daily Progress.xlsx"
            Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
            erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `if Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 3).Value`what's the point of this?

Comment: Why don't you step through the code?  Which line fails?

Comment: This value changes based on the datasheet, so I need it to equal whatever the value is in column three.  I don't know if I did it right, but it didn't error me out, so I thought it was good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes around the A are not the correct character. Replace them with the double-quote next to the Enter key.

Also, include the ActiveSheet reference for the Rows.Count immediately after the 'A'.

Comment: Thank you.  That went right over my head.  It works now.  I will accept this answer as soon as i can.  Says I have to wait 6 minutes.  I feel dumb! Sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 1):

Those quotes look suspiciously deviant to me...

You have the following:

```
Range(“A” & Rows.Count)
      ^ ^
   ---¦ ¦---
  ¦         ¦
Chr(147) Chr(148)
```

Those are in fact `Chr(147)` and `Chr(148)` - what you need is `"` which is `Chr(34)`